# How can you read the contents of an array pointer passed to a method mocked with googlemock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am passing a pointer to an array to a function, which I am mocking with googlemock. I would like to verify the contents of the arguments, which works fine for scalars, but I am only able to fetch the first element of the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
class InterfaceTest : public ::testing::Test {};
class MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs, (int*, int*));
};

void testfunc_pointer(MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs* func_interface) {
  int testscalar = 123;
  int testarray[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  func_interface->fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(&testscalar, &testarray[0]);
}

TEST_F(InterfaceTest, TestFuncInterfacePointerArgs) {
  MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
  int passed_scalar = 0;
  int passed_array[3] = {0, 0, 0};
  // int passed_array = 0;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_, testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(
        testing::SaveArgPointee<0>(&passed_scalar),
        testing::SaveArgPointee<1>(passed_array)
    ));
  testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
  std::cout << passed_scalar << std::endl; // prints 123
  std::cout << passed_array[0] << " " << passed_array[1] << " " << passed_array[2] << std::endl; // prints 1 0 0
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

How can I modify this test so I am able to verify all three array elements?
I also tried using the `SetArrayArgument` functionality as defined in the [documentation](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html):

```
TEST_F(InterfaceTest, TestFuncInterfacePointerArgs) {
  MockFortranFuncInterfacePointerArgs mock_func_interface;
  int passed_scalar = 0;
  int passed_array[3] = {0, 0, 0};
  // int passed_array = 0;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_, testing::_))
    .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(
        testing::SaveArgPointee<0>(&passed_scalar),
        testing::SetArrayArgument<1>(passed_array, passed_array + 3)
    ));
  testfunc_pointer(&mock_func_interface);
  std::cout << passed_scalar << std::endl; // prints 123
  std::cout << passed_array[0] << " " << passed_array[1] << " " << passed_array[2] << std::endl; // prints 0 0 0
}
```

But this doesn't store anything and `passed_array` remains unmodified after the function call. How can I verify the arguments passed to my function, without modifying the `testfunc_pointer` function?

Comment: Switch to [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and forget that C-style arrays exist in the language.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible without a custom lambda/Action.

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_func_interface, fortran_interface_test_func_pointerargs(testing::_, testing::_))
.WillOnce(testing::Invoke([&](int* scalar, int* array){
    passed_scalar = *scalar;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        passed_array[i] = array[i];
    }
})); 
//you could still use SaveArgPointee for first argument, but that requires some more work using With() to separate arguments
```

You can't use `SaveArg` or `SaveArgPointee`, because that would only save a pointer to the array and the array is dead as soon as `testfunc_pointer` returns - you have to copy the contents while still inside mock call.
And `Set*` family of Actions set the argument passed to mock, not the argument passed to expectation. You could notice a difference in `testfunc_pointer` after the call to mock, but it won't change your local variables in test.

That leaves us with having to write a custom lambda/Action to fit the needs.